# Connection timeout to streams.canonical.com when installing juju

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

The `.cloud-install/commands.log` file shows this error:

```
Attempt 5 to download tools from https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/agent/1.25.3/juju-1.25.3-trusty-amd64.tgz...
curl: (7) Failed to connect to streams.canonical.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

It attempts to download the tar file five times and then fails.
[This is where the node stops and nothing happens here after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0x8v.jpg).
The complete log file is available at: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15390451/

Comment: Load this URL in a browser and see if you get a download dialog: https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/agent/1.25.3/juju-1.25.3-trusty-amd64.tgz

Comment: yes, I am able to download it.

Comment: How are you trying to install juju? Which instructions are you following?

Comment: Try and see if these solve your problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/463612/maas-juju-bootstrap-connection-error and http://askubuntu.com/questions/465508/juju-bootstrap-debug-failed-to-connect-https-streams-canonical-com

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-openstack-with-autopilot https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/juju-quick-start.html and some from https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0IzrPf_rfUFrQdA-mf4XEfHl_O3IuYx6

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it!!!!
Seems like for JUJU bootstrap to work IP forwarding needs to be enabled on MAAS server.

Refer: https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/issues/901

Comment: please give a detailed answer of how you solved it. it might be helpful to someone else in the future.